# How to run a function for each row in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, validation

I'm a Python newbie and trying to write code that checks if a nested list has a valid set of numbers. Each row and each column have to be valid. I have written a function called check_sequence which validates if a list has a valid set of numbers. How would I call that function from another to check to see if the row is valid? So for example, I need something like this for check_rows:

```
check_sequence(list):
  checks if list is valid

check_rows(list):
  For each of the rows in the nested list call check_sequence
```

Here is my code for check_sequence:

```
def check_sequence(mylist):
    pos = 0
    sequence_counter = 1
    while pos < len(mylist):
        print "The pos is: " + " " + str(pos)
        print "The sequence_counter is:" + " " + str(sequence_counter)
        for number in mylist:
            print "The number is:" + " " + str(number)
            if number == sequence_counter:
                sequence_counter = sequence_counter + 1
                pos = pos + 1
                break
            else:
                # if list is at the last position on the last item
                if sequence_counter not in mylist:
                    print "The pos is:" + " " + str(pos) + " and the last position is:"  + " "  + str(mylist[len(mylist) - 1])
                    print "False"
                    return False
    print "True"
    return True
```

So I'd call the main method like below:

```
check_square([[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 3, 1],
           [3, 1, 2]])

def check_square(list):
   if check_rows() and check_columns() == True:
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

Comment: Lists do not have "rows" and "columns". Please try to be *precise*

Comment: If you can add some code that constructs a sample of your nested list, answers are more likely to be in the right direction

Comment: @JoeP I've added more code.

Comment: MMM i'm still can't understand what do you want to achieve, can you put it in words? also an example list to input and how do you expect the output? that will help a lot!

Comment: @DamianLattenero ok an example list would be something like this:

`[[1,2,3],
 [2,3,1],
 [3,1,2]]`

The output would return True if numbers 1 to n appear once in the row and column and False if they don't. So I'm checking to see if a sudoku square is valid(not sure if you play the game.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an iterative for loop?

```
 check_sequence(list):
    #your check here

 check_rows(list):
     for row in list:
         if not check_sequence(row):
             return False
     return True
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you. I just want to return True or False.

Comment: OP never really specified what was needed to be returned. I was merely showing a implementation of an iterative for loop and the program flow

Comment: Edited to add returns

Answer (score 1):

Given the nested list is *row oriented* (the rows are the lowest dimension), you can simply use:

```
check_rows(list):
    return all(check_sequence(sublist) for sublist in list)
```

Here we thus use the `all(..)` builtin: it evaluates to `True` if and only if the *truthiness* of all elements the generator (boldface part) is `True`, otherwise the result is `False`. So from the moment one of the rows is not valid, the matrix is not valid.

If on the other hand the nested list is *column oriented* (the columns are the lowest dimension), we will first need to do a *transpose* using `zip`:

```
check_rows(list):
    return all(check_sequence(list(sublist)) for sublist in zip(*list))
```

The `zip(*..)` transposes the `list` and we use `list(..)` to make sure that `check_sequence(..)` is still working with lists (if any iterable is sufficient, the `list(..)` part can be omitted.

Comment: I think this is brilliant, just perfect, but for someone who is starting is a lot to take in! don't you think? but, plus one for great answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that'll work for any arbitrary 2D list.

```
l = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]]
try:
    if len([1 for x in reduce(lambda x, y :x + y, l) if type(x) != type(0)]) > 0:
        raise Exception

catch Exception:
   pass # error, do something
```

The intuition is to flatten the list and then successively check if its type is `int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was just providing an alternate solution to check for validity without needing to use functions... Have made a couple of edits.

Comment: @Shiva wow... that's a lot of functional understanding! plus one, really like it, but for someone who is starting, again, don't you think that's a lot to take in?

Comment: @DamianLattenero I agree. There are already excellent answers covering the basics. I wanted to give an answer to someone looking for a more pythonic solution to the same problem. :)

Comment: @Shiva that's a cool way you have show, it's good to have more than one point of view

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate in two function, and think the first one will return the complete check for each value of the other:

```
def check_sequence(lis):
  ret = True
  for row in lis:
    ret = ret and check_rows(row)
  return ret

def check_rows(row):
  ret = True
  for elem in row:
    pass #do your checking
  return ret
```

a concrete example could be:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]]
def check_sequence(lis):
  ret = True
  for row in lis:
    ret = ret and check_rows(row)
  return ret

def check_rows(row):
  return 1 in row #ask if 1 belongs to the list

check_sequence(l) ---> True
check_sequence([[1],[2,3]]) ---> False
```

Comment: In check_rows where you have `for elem in row:` when I pass in my check_sequence function after that will it check for that element only or the whole row?

Comment: @johnnewbie25 In check_rows, my bad name, will check only one row, it means, is a simple list of elements just like [1,2,3], do you understand?

Comment: @johnnewbie25 I can update the answer with an example, for example, check if every row has the number "1", so you can see and then do you case, but better, could you add to the question what is your list, or a similar list of list, and your expected result?

Comment: @johnnewbie25 Also I updated the answer, see if it helps

Comment: Ok, I think we are getting closer. The problem I was having is I don't know how to express in code how to use my check_sequence method that I have posted in my original question to check each row of a list. When I think of iterating through a list I think of choosing each item in that list and not the whole row. I'm not quite sure what's happening in your check_rows method.